# How to attach this listener in an activity

Tags: java, android

I was wondering how do i attach this(OnGenericMotionListener) listener inside an activity. Do i have to register it to each view? thanks

note: please provide code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add any interface to a class in java you just need to add the word implements and then the class name to the top of the activity declaration. So to add the OnGenericMotionListener you would use the code below.

```
    public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnGenericMotionListener {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
               super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

               TextView myView = new TextView(this);

               myView.setOnGenericMotionListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onGenericMotion(View view, MotionEvent event) {


               return false;
            }

     }
```

This would set the GenericMotionListener for myView so when the event occurs it will call the onGenericMotion function inside of your activity. If you want to attach it to multiple views just use a switch on the id of the view passed to the onGenericMotion function.

Comment: so this is only specific to myView if it is then why is it being passed the view in the first parameter...Is there a listener that listens to all views at once?

Comment: @MikeG, You can attach multiple views to the same listener, in that case, how will you identify which view is invoking your Callback? For this reason, the calling View is sent as a parameter....for your convenience.